# in which/where when discussing a country

Tags: prepositions

In formal writing, it'd be better to write:

> the house in which I was born

than

> the house where I was born

but does the same 'rule' apply when using a country as a locality? E.g.

> In August I go to France, in which there were elections in April.

or should it be:

> In August I go to France, where there were elections in April.

Comment: What does _which_ refer to in you example about France? You can go to _**the** country in which there were elections_, but unless I really missed a big event, there is only one France, _where_ there were elections. Formal or not, _France, in which_ ain't flying.

Comment: Who told  you *the house in which* is better than *the house where* in 'formal' writing? This is quite untrue.

Comment: "In which" is probably only better if "where" isn't possible. For example, "That's the box in which my cat arrived." (Of course, in natural speech you would say: "That's the box my cat arrived in.")

Answer (score 1):

(Edited based on a comment. I should have read the question more carefully.)

I don't know that I'd say "in which" would be *better* in any case. I would say (1) the two mean the same and (2) "where" is less formal-sounding than "in which," though by no means is it overly informal.

And in the country case, as the commenter says, "in which" sounds a bit odd. Taking a few example sentences:

- I am in the house in which I was born
- I am in the town in which there was a hurricane
- I am in the country in which there were elections in April
- I am in the solar system in which the earth resides

It seems like, the larger the "place", the odder "in which" sounds. Honestly, I don't like "in which" in any of these cases personally. It sounds overly formal to me.

Comment: I don't think it sounds that odd with _the country_, but it _does_ sound odd with _France_. Just like _the city in which they built a church_ is fine, but not _London in which they built a church_.